# Gradle. Тянуть зависимости из нексуса и дублировать туда новые

Tags: gradle, зависимости, nexus

есть многомодульный преокт на Gradle. Доступ к инетренету есть только на локальном физическом компе, с которого можно тянуть зависимости с Интернета. 
Есть Nexus репозиторий откуда планируется выкачивать зависимости. 
Как настроить градл так, чтобы при локальной компиляции он тянул зависимости из Интернета и деплоил в нексус, а если нет Интернета, тянул с нексуса?

На Maven это делается с помощью mirrors. там это легко делать. Но на градле столкнулся со сложностями.

Comment: настроить лучше локальный Nexus в режиме proxy. mirror в maven как раз и работает с Nexus в режиме proxy.

Comment: она и  так настроена так. проблема в том. что не знаю как заставить градл новые артефакты дублировать в нексус.

Comment: это не задача системы сборки. это должен делать ваш Nexus. его надо настроить в режим прокси.